# Got stuck at step 4

Tags: java, object, methods

1. Create a Student Class with the following instance variables:

   ````
   -LastName
   -MatNo
   -Age
   -GPA e.g A+, B-```
   ````
2. Create a Constructor that takes all the instance variables (class fields) as input parameters.
3. Create Accessor(Getter)  and Mutator (Setter) methods for each of the instance variables.
4. Create a method called calAge that returns the age of a student based on yearofBirth as input parameter.
5. Create a Tester Program to test the Student class. Do the following:

   ````
   -Calculate the age of each student object created based on the calAge method.
   -Change the GPA of each student by calling the Mutator method of GPA.
   -Make sure data about each of the students is printed to the Console.```
   ````

My code so far:

```
package ict;

public class Student {


    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int mattNo;
    private int age;
    private String gpa;

    public Student(String first, String last, int matt, int ag, String gp)
    {
        setFirstName(first);
        setLastName(last);
        setMattNo(matt);
        setAge(ag);
        setGpa(gp);

    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getMattNo() {
        return mattNo;
    }

    public void setMattNo(int mattNo) {
        this.mattNo = mattNo;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getGpa() {
        return gpa;
    }

    public void setGpa(String gpa) {
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }

}
```

Comment: current date - yearOfBirth = current age.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method called calAge that returns the age of a student based
   on yearofBirth as input parameter.

```
int calAge (int yearofBirth) {
     Year y = Year.now();
     return y.getValue () - yearOfBirth;
}
```

**now** this does not seem to be a very good way, I think you need to consider the month and day that you were born.

**also** consider to make this method static

Comment: You're right, it's not a good way. Your calculation only works if the person has already had their birthday for the current year otherwise you need to subtract **1**. The date of birth is important so as to now if the birthday has already taken place.